# Joomla module with no display on frontpage

Tags: module, joomla, show, frontpage

I have been developing a Joomla module. This is my first module development.

Is it possible that I enable a module in Joomla and let there is no output in front page?

Because I don't want to display anything in a front page position, just show a popup.

my tmpl/default.php content is:

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); // no direct access ?>
```

and in module entry, I commented the line:

```
//require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_blabla'));
```

However, the content of a text-area parameter(backend) is shown in front page.

**SOLUTION:**

There was a variable named "$content" in my php code. Whatever i assign to it, displayed in front page. Now I changed the variable name from $content to something else, there is nothing diplayed in front page. This is what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the Module Manager, go to your module and in the bottom left, you can set which pages you want to display the module on. Unselect the Homepage menu item.

Comment: Hello Lodder, when you select "No Pages", then the module is not loaded and no popup shown.

Comment: of course. popup won't show if it's set to "No Pages". If you want it to show, you need to assign it to a page ;)